# Error in using Firestore with Android Architecture Components

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-livedata

I have an activity where a User is made to log in. Once the User logs in, the User detail is uploaded to the Firebase which is observed using the `LiveData` in the activity.

The problem is even though the data is successfully uploaded, the LiveData is showing that an error occurred.

**Activity**

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val RC_SIGN_IN = 123

private val viewModel by viewModel<LoginViewModel>() // Lazy inject ViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    loginUser()
    observeLoginLiveData()
}


private fun observeLoginLiveData() {
    viewModel.onAuthenticationSuccessful().observe(this, Observer { result ->
        when (result) {
            is Result.Loading -> {
            }

            is Result.Success<*> -> {
                startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
                finish()
            }

            is Result.Error -> {
                clLogin.showSnackbar(R.string.error_login) {}
                Timber.e(result.errorMessage)
            }
        }
    })
 }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class LoginViewModel(val repo: LoginRepository) : ViewModel() {

private val _loginLiveData = MutableLiveData<Result>()
private val loginLiveData: LiveData<Result>
    get() = _loginLiveData

fun onAuthenticationSuccessful(): LiveData<Result> {
    _loginLiveData.value = Result.Loading
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _loginLiveData.value = repo.uploadUserDetails()
    }
    return loginLiveData
 }
}
```

**Repository**

```
class LoginRepository {

suspend fun uploadUserDetails(): Result {
val response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val currentUser = FirebaseUtils.getCurrentUser()
        val user = User(currentUser?.displayName, currentUser?.email, currentUser?.photoUrl.toString())

        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection(FirebaseReferences.COLLECTION_USERS)
            .add(user)
    }

    return if (response.isSuccessful) {
        Result.Success("true")
    } else {
        Result.Error("Error uploading user data")
    }
 }
}
```

I have also tried using `response.isComplete` but it also returns false everytime.

I don't know what I am missing here. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What error is livedata showing? Do you have some error logs?

Comment: The LiveData emits value "Error uploading user data".

Comment: You have to wait until the FIrebase task is completed via `addOnCompleteListener()`, that's why `response.isComplete` is always false.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment, I changed the code to wait for the result as shown below and now I am getting the proper response:

**Changed ViewModel**

```
class LoginViewModel(val repo: LoginRepository) : ViewModel() {

private val _loginLiveData = MutableLiveData<Result>()
private val loginLiveData: LiveData<Result>
    get() = _loginLiveData

fun onAuthenticationSuccessful(): LiveData<Result> {
    _loginLiveData.value = Result.Loading

    viewModelScope.launch {
        repo.uploadUserDetails().addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                _loginLiveData.value = Result.Success("true")
            } else {
                _loginLiveData.value = Result.Error("Error uploading user data")
            }
        }
    }
    return loginLiveData
 }
}
```

**Changed Repository**

```
class LoginRepository {

suspend fun uploadUserDetails(): Task<DocumentReference> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val currentUser = FirebaseUtils.getCurrentUser()
    val user = User(currentUser?.displayName, currentUser?.email, currentUser?.photoUrl.toString())

    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection(FirebaseReferences.COLLECTION_USERS)
        .add(user)
 }
}
```